# Unable to switch on logging collector for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, logging, configuration

I tried to switch on query logging with PostgreSQL (version 9.6.8) and it seems like the server hangs when starting with the logging collector enabled. I started with the following conf and noticed that it works as long as 'logging_collector = on' is commented out. The log always complains about ipv6 but it still does even when it's working. Other than that - nothing in the logs. Does anyone have the faintest idea what could be the problem? Any hints are appreciated! I'm on a Linux x86_64 system.

```
autovacuum = on
datestyle = 'iso, dmy'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 150
shared_buffers = 256MB
tcp_keepalives_idle = 2
tcp_keepalives_interval = 2
tcp_keepalives_count = 5
work_mem = 4MB
#logging_collector = on
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_line_prefix = '%quser=%u @ host(port)=%r sessid=%c '
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
```

In the pg_log directory, there is a log with the following lines:

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-09-10 12:57:09 GMT
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the `pg_log` subdirectory of the data directory?

Comment: Yes, there is a log with a few lines, I edited the post.

Comment: So everything works as expected. What is your problem?

Comment: It sure does, but the scripts I'm using to start the postgreSQL server (along with a bunch of other applications) suddenly fails when switching the flag on. Looks almost like a timeout issue. But maybe I should rather look into the scripts?

Comment: Yes, could be a problem with your scripts.

Comment: I found the answer, nothing wrong with postgreSQL itself. The scripts were waiting for output, and then failed when it didnt get any, since I specified the log output elsewhere. :-) Thanks for your help!